# InkScape pixelates SVG with embedded xlink:href SVG files for nodes in a D3js graph

Tags: d3.js, svg, inkscape

I have produced a tree diagram using svg as rectangular nodes in D3js. Here is the bl.ock for it:
http://bl.ocks.org/Coola85/2450007804d9508866616640ac1272b8/fea7a37158edf9accd749a6fa3399800bea9bbad 
The output in the browser looks like this and the aim is to be able to save this as an SVG:
[image: d3 tree map with svg as images]
I use SVG Crowbar (https://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/) to save the svg using Google Chrome. 
When I try to open the svg in InkScape it pixelates the rectangles and it appears like this. 
[image: Pixelated nodes in InkScape]
Adobe Illustrator completely fails to open the rectangles at all stating that a plugin is required. I searched everywhere but no such plugin exists.
I would like to find a way so that the images (in this case rectangles) still appear sharp and are vector paths/shapes.
The XML editor for inkscape shows that it is using the xlink:href for the svg file as shown below. 
[image]

Here is the code for the Main SVG file output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="960" height="500" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="font-family:serif;height:500px;perspective-origin:480px 250px;transform-origin:480px 250px;width:960px;-moz-text-size-adjust:auto;">
    <g transform="translate(120,20)" style="font-family:serif;height:auto;overflow:visible;overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:visible;perspective-origin:480px 250px;transform-origin:0px 0px;width:auto;-moz-text-size-adjust:auto;">
        <path class="link" style="font-family:serif;height:auto;overflow:visible;overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:visible;perspective-origin:480px 250px;transform-origin:0px 0px;width:auto;-moz-text-size-adjust:auto;fill:none;stroke:rgb(255, 0, 0);stroke-width:2px;" d="M0,230C90,230 90,115 180,115" />
        <path class="link" style="font-family:serif;height:auto;overflow:visible;overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:visible;perspective-origin:480px 250px;transform-origin:0px 0px;width:auto;-moz-text-size-adjust:auto;fill:none;stroke:rgb(0, 128, 0);stroke-width:2px;" d="M0,230C90,230 90,345 180,345" />
        <g class="node" transform="translate(180,345)" style="font-family:serif;height:auto;overflow:visible;overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:visible;perspective-origin:480px 250px;transform-origin:0px 0px;width:auto;-moz-text-size-adjust:auto;">
            <image xlink:href="rect2.svg" x="-12px" y="-12px" width="24px" height="24px" style="font-family:serif;height:auto;perspective-origin:480px 250px;transform-origin:0px 0px;width:auto;-moz-text-size-adjust:auto;" />
            <text x="15" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start" style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:12px;height:auto;line-height:14.4px;overflow:visible;overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:visible;perspective-origin:480px 250px;transform-origin:0px 0px;width:auto;-moz-text-size-adjust:auto;">Level 2: B</text>
        </g>
        <g class="node" transform="translate(180,115)" style="font-family:serif;height:auto;overflow:visible;overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:visible;perspective-origin:480px 250px;transform-origin:0px 0px;width:auto;-moz-text-size-adjust:auto;">
            <image xlink:href="rect2.svg" x="-12px" y="-12px" width="24px" height="24px" style="font-family:serif;height:auto;perspective-origin:480px 250px;transform-origin:0px 0px;width:auto;-moz-text-size-adjust:auto;" />
            <text x="15" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start" style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:12px;height:auto;line-height:14.4px;overflow:visible;overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:visible;perspective-origin:480px 250px;transform-origin:0px 0px;width:auto;-moz-text-size-adjust:auto;">Level 2: A</text>
        </g>
        <g class="node" transform="translate(0,230)" style="font-family:serif;height:auto;overflow:visible;overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:visible;perspective-origin:480px 250px;transform-origin:0px 0px;width:auto;-moz-text-size-adjust:auto;">
            <image xlink:href="rect.svg" x="-12px" y="-12px" width="24px" height="24px" style="font-family:serif;height:auto;perspective-origin:480px 250px;transform-origin:0px 0px;width:auto;-moz-text-size-adjust:auto;" />
            <text x="-15" dy=".35em" text-anchor="end" style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:12px;height:auto;line-height:14.4px;overflow:visible;overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:visible;perspective-origin:480px 250px;transform-origin:0px 0px;width:auto;-moz-text-size-adjust:auto;text-anchor:end;">Top Level</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to be expected in the current Inkscape version (0.92.3) and previous versions that support display of linked SVG files.

The next major version will still display embedded and linked SVG files as raster images, but it will allow you to set an import resolution, so you can make them large enough so they will appear crisp.

But this is just how it **displays** in Inkscape - if you plan to use the SVG file in a browser later, it doesn't matter if it looks ugly while you are editing it. It will look correct, if the browser (or whichever other program you plan to use) can display linked SVG images correctly.

If you need to export a PNG image, then you should consider importing the rectangles, maybe using clones. You can use the align+distribute dialog to swap positions of objects, this makes it easy to place them in the exact same location as they were before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Moini. My ultimate aim is that I would like to be able to edit the svg file (change size of nodes and links etc). Is there a way using some script to embed the nested svg files to create a complete svg file rather than the linked one?

Comment: I don't know of anything like that with the current version 0.92.3. It works on master branch, though (I've tested the functionality for Jabier, who implemented it).

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to what is master branch?

Comment: It's the development branch of the Inkscape software. See https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape - and if you want to install such a version, visit https://inkscape.org/en/release/master/?latest=1 for instructions